# Setting NSString as UI Label text

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, nsstring, uilabel

.h file:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *output;
```

.m file:

```
@synthesize output;
```

and I want to define a string which carries the text of the UILabel so I wrote

```
NSString *var =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",output.text];
```

However, it tells me that I have used "output" as an undeclared identifier. What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance

*Edit 1:

Thanks for your suggestions. However, I get this same error with all of the suggestions given:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYjqz.png)

Comment: Its working fine on my side. Can you show me your error?

Comment: There's no need to synthesize the property.  There's no point to using `initWithFormat`, when you can just assign `self.output.text` directly.  You need to find a tutorial that's been updated more recently than 5 years ago.

Comment: Try to use like NSString *var =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",output.text];

Comment: did you connect `output` property with `UILabel` of xib/stroyboard?

Comment: glowstonetrees I posted my answer.It gives you the solution.Check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did not connect the label with xib or storyboard properly.Kindly again connect the label with xib or storyboard correctly with the following screenshots and coding.

**FIRST : I drag and drop the Label from the Object Library**
[image: I drag and drop the Label from the Object Library]

**SECOND : CLICK control + mouse on label and drag that label to ViewController.h**
[image]

**THIRD : Now BOX shows with default cursor in Name field**
[image]

**FOUR : Finally give the Label Name in Name Field of BOX**
[image]

Once I did that Now the View Controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelStringText;

@end
```

Then in ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize labelStringText;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  labelStringText.text = @"";
  NSString *strLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",labelStringText.text];
        //OR
  NSString *strLabelText = labelStringText.text;
}
```

for your simple understanding I set the label.text to string in viewDidLoad.You just set the string where you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, it only seems to work when I put it in viewDidLoad, but I get the error message again once I put it just under @implementation.

Comment: If you put the code under @implementation it shows the error definitely.You need to call that in viewDidLoad,buttonAction or some other method.

Answer (score 0):

For properties you have to use `self` to access them.

So you should use `self.output.text`

Comment: OP has `synthesize` the `property`. So, don't need `self`

Answer (score 0):

To get access to your properties you should use self

So it should look

```
NSString *var =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",self.output.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
NSString *var =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",_output.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a Referencing Outlet from the Label to the View Controller, and put the code inside of viewDidLoad or another function.

**First click on the label and drag from New Referencing Outlet to the View Controller:**

[image: First click on the label and drag from New Referencing Outlet to the View Controller.]

**Then select your property from the list:**

[image: Then select your property from the list.]

**Finally, you should see a result like this:**
[image: Finally, you should see a result like this:]

The code:

***.h:***

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *output;

@end
```

***.m:***

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize output;

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    

    NSString *var =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",output.text];

    NSLog(@"%@", var);

}

@end
```

Comment: No, it's different. You used Assistant editor which both creates a property and makes the reference outlet at the same time. Assuming the OP has already written the code, he/she just needs to make the reference outlet connection instead of declaring a property again. Thank you for your "constructive" criticism.